# avro format, seeking to a position or skipping rows via python

Tags: python, avro

I'm using Apache Avro 1.8.2  to read a large avro file. However, I would like to skip the first 'N' records or process individual parts of the file with 5 threads.

Is there any easy way to seek within an avro file without causing data corruption rather than looping through each record sequentially ? I believe it is split-able format, but I'm not sure if python avro module supports jumping to a particular position safely.

Currently all I can do is to process it row by row:

```
reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
i = 0
for user in reader:
    i += 1
    if (i>10000):
      break
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of a way to do it in the standard `avro` library, but in [`fastavro`](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro) there is a `block_reader` interface that you should be able to use.

This might look like the following:

```
import fastavro

with open("file.avro", "rb") as fp:
    for block in fastavro.block_reader(fp, schema):
        process_block(block)
```

`process_block` would be the function that would be running off in a thread, and it would do something like the following:

```
def process_block(block):
    for record in block:
        process_record(record)
```